# Pidgin will not connect to MSN any longer

Tags: connection, pidgin, msn

About 3 weeks ago, pidgin stopped connecting to the MSN network and I get the "Connection error from Notification server:
Connection refused" message. This issue occurs in both my Ubuntu 12.04 machine and my WIn7 machine. Trillian on my windows machine connects just fine to MSN, so I dont suspect a network issue.

My settings are: messenger.hotmail.com
Port: 1863
Proxy type. Use environmental settings

The "use HTTP method option results in it actually trying to connect, but it never does, it just says "connecting.....". I have attempted to change just about every other setting, with no luck.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 2):

If I were to guess, I'd say it stopped working slightly more than 6 weeks ago, when the [MSN messenger network was closed down](http://www.forbes.com/sites/amitchowdhry/2014/08/31/msn-messenger-is-completely-shutting-down-on-october-31st/), so I don't know what Trillian is connecting to.

Microsoft wants you to move to skype, which is available for ubuntu, and you should be able to log in using the same microsoft account and find all your friends still there.

Comment: Aren't I just with the times. :/ Idon't suppose there is a way to get skype on pidgin without the skype client runnning.

Comment: and very odd my trillian client still connects

Answer (score 1):

*Microsoft keeps shutting down "unofficial" methods of access and
applications - of which Pidgin is one.* 
Pidgin developer describes the issue https://pidgin.im/pipermail/support/2015-January/028600.html

**!There is an workaround!**

**skypeweb plugin for allows to use MSN account.** 
Contacts and messages service are available.

***How to set up***

1. Build and install SkypeWeb Plugin for Pidgin:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libpurple-dev libjson-glib-dev cmake gcc        
   git clone git://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin.git
   cd skype4pidgin/skypeweb
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake ..
   cpack
   sudo dpkg -i skypeweb-1.4.0-Linux.deb
   ```

(correspond to https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb instruction)

2. Login into https://web.skype.com/ (Once, for activation skype web)
3. Open Pidgin. Create an account for Skype(HTTP) protocol

***Information about current situation with MSN***

[ismsndeadyet.com](http://ismsndeadyet.com/) site says:

**Update 2017/08:**

> The servers that implemented MSNP21 and MSNP22 are gone, two years after
>   MSNP18 and all the other versions were discontinued.
>   MSNP24 still works, but it uses different servers and was (is?) primarily 
>   used by skype clients. So for the purposes of this status page, MSNP24 is 
>   skype, not MSN.

**Update 2016/02:**

> The MSNP18 protocol and all the older versions are gone. MSNP21/22/24
>   are still there.
>   Most clients still don't implement newer versions. Some are listed on
>   the right column.